# Maintaining Wallet between payment gateways

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, paypal, payment-gateway

I am building an application which needs to maintain a Wallet and the for transactions we will be using `PayPal`(also considering `Square,Cash App`). I have experience in `PayPal` but my use case is as follows :

1. There will be three types of users(`Super-Admin, Admin and Client`)
2. All will make payment from `PayPal`(for now).
3. The application will have to maintain `Wallet` for `Admin and Client`.
4. Both users will transfer money to application `wallet via PayPal`.
5. And when the `Super-Admin` wants to charge money, money will be charged from the Wallet.
6. Admin needs to disburse money to `Client from the Wallet to Client's wallet`.
7. Client can withdraw money from the `Wallet to PayPal account.`

So I need advice about how can I implement this feature.
What would be the flow ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a unique wallet object for each user with userId as a key. For transferring money from one user to another user, move the money from the wallet of the source user to the destination user. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Ido Thank you for reply. Your idea is nice but is the money transferred from PayPal to wallet ? or just database record ? Because, if it's database only thing then, for example : if admin transfers $10 to wallet as database record but the actual transaction is not shown in PayPal and has not been deducted, admin can use that amount via PayPal and when the super-admin will try to deduct the amount from wallet the PayPal account will be empty, so the super-admin cannot deduct $10 in reality. Isn't it ?

Comment: @sudeepshakya Yes, the walled is a database record. My understanding was that users should be able to transfer money from PayPal to the application. The application would need an account to which the user can send the money, if this transaction is successful you add the transferred amount to the users walled.

Comment: @Ido Thank you for the reply. Any other solution ? Because when you perform transactions to other accounts, fee will be incurred, every wallet transfer fee, which is expensive.I guess in US, PayPal to PayPal is free though.